# Is there a cleaner alternative to using events within this code?

Tags: c#

Hi first of sorry if the question is not worded brilliantly.
And for the question, Is there a better way to achieve the following:

```
public class UntouchableClass
{
    public event GetStringValue GetTestString;
    public delegate string GetStringValue(string id, EventArgs e);

    private string myValue;

    public void SimulateWork()
    {
        myValue = GetTestString.Invoke("ResultFromSimulatedWork", null);
    }
    public string WhatDidIAssign()
    {
        return myValue;
    }
}
```

and then it is used like this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UntouchableClass classy = new UntouchableClass();
        classy.GetTestString += (s, ev) => 
        {
            return "RandomValue from " + s;
        };
        classy.SimulateWork();
        MessageBox.Show(classy.WhatDidIAssign());
    }
```

I am simply asking for better alternatives, if you could point me in a direction or show an example of something, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite it like this, using [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void SimulateWork(Func<string, string> myFunc)
{
    if (myFunc != null)
    {
        myValue = myFunc("ResultFromSimulatedWork");
    }
}
```

The call to it would look like:

```
classy.SimulateWork(i => "RandomValue from " + i);
```

Comment: I changed it a bit and I am getting a result, I will try a small test case with this. and get back to you. thank you.

Comment: I got this to do exactly what I needed.

Comment: Yes!  Change your GetStringValue to a **property** of type Func <string,string>

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use event handlers that return a value, that's a big no-no.

Instead, use a simple delegate:

```
Func<string, string> getSomeString;

public string DoWork()
{
  return getSomeString?.Invoke(someArgument);
}
```

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you might want to pass the delegate either through the constructor of the class or directly as an argument to the `DoWork` method (`string DoWork(Function<string, string> func)`).

If you want to separate the work being done from the return value, you might want to consider using an async method that returns `Task<string>` instead of just `string` (or in your case, using a field that's read by a separate method). But again, this is pure guesswork on my part on what you're actually trying to achieve - your question isn't clear in that regard :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
public string SimulateWork()
{
    return GetTestString.Invoke("ResultFromSimulatedWork", null);
}
```

And then use it as such:

```
MessageBox.Show(classy.SimulateWork());
```

Comment: I might not have made it clear enough, but I want to know if there is a better way than using events. It feels dirty... yours does shorten it up a bit though.